# Браузерная игра на Unity3d без web player, возможно ли?

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d, веб-программирование, webgl

Можно ли сделать браузерную игру на Unity3d без установки специального плагина web player? (например при помощи только webgl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да. Вам понадобится недавно вышедшая Unity3D 5, она поддерживает WebGL, asm.js и иже.

См. [Getting Started with WebGL Development](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-gettingstarted.html).